# How to change URL in the client with a redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using C# core 2.2 MVC and am attempting to implement friendly URLs.
I have started to implement Rewrite rule and this is working fine.

BUT

The URL in the browser changes from the friendly URL to the ugly controller/action/{id}.

```cs
public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
{
    var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
    var path = request.Path.ToString().ToLower();

    if (_friendlyUrlMap.ContainsKey(path))
    {
        var redirectUrl = _friendlyUrlMap[path];

        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        // Attempt - 01
        response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently;
        context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
        response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = redirectUrl;
    }
}
```

What I would like is what I am doing wrong and have the URL stay as the friendly URL.

Answer (score 1):

> What I would like is what I am doing wrong and have the URL stay as the friendly URL.

You could directly change the path to the redirectUrl in your ApplyRule method ,  I set some values ​​for `_friendlyUrlMap` to facilitate testing since I don't know the definition of `_friendlyUrlMap` :

```
 public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        var path = request.Path.ToString().ToLower();

        var _friendlyUrlMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        _friendlyUrlMap.Add("/filetotexttohtml", "/Home/FileToTextToHtml");
        _friendlyUrlMap.Add("/convertfile", "/Home/FileToTextToHtml");

        if (_friendlyUrlMap.ContainsKey(path))
        {
            var redirectUrl = _friendlyUrlMap[path];
            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            context.HttpContext.Request.Path = redirectUrl;
        }
    }
```

You could add `ApplyRule` method in Startup.cs , then add it in `Configure` method like below:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
                       .Add(ApplyRule)
                       );

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: sorry but I'm getting a 404 with this. where in the order of the startup.cs  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) did you add this?

Comment: @StephenCossgrove ,please check my updated in Configure method of startup.cs